# Missing } in quantified repetition. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression: '{>>>HERE>>>.*}'

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I get this error:

> Missing } in quantified repetition. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression: '{>>>HERE>>>.*}'. Details:

When running:

```
select regexp_substr(jsons_arrays,'\{.*\}',1,1)
from table
```

Field `json_arrays` is an invalid json such as:

```
{'a': '20', 'b': '30'}, {'b': '1'}, {'a': '112', 'b': '34'}
```

The goal is to split this field into three valid jsons:

1. `{'a': '20', 'b': '30'}`
2. `{'b': '1'}`
3. `{'a': '112', 'b': '34'}`

Maybe is the application of the posix substring in the `regexp_substr` function?
How can I add the pattern of 'anything between {}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double-escape `{}` on Redshift.

For example, `'\\{\\}` to match `{}` literally.